# How to upload files from client side with a php form?

Tags: php, forms, upload, ftp, applet

I am making a form where the users should be able to attach files that can be relevant to the form data.

I'm facing the problem that I can't upload more than 2MB of files in a POST request since that's the default upload limit with post, and I don't have access to change that limit since the server is hosted by a service provider that just doesn't allow that.

I know how to upload via FTP with php, but that is all server-side code, and if I'm not mistaken, that will not work with uploading files from client-side, eg: a client browses for a file, then submits.

While looking for solutions on SO and elsewhere, I came across endless terms like chunking, JSP, Java applets, silverlight, etc... To the point that I am lost. I know I can't use Java applet since it will not work on mobile phones.

To make it clear, Im asking for any solution where a client can browse for a file and upload it with (or before) a php form, that can still work on mobile (if possible).

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: can I at least get a comment as of why I got a negative vote? I know I didn't post any code but I think it's irrelevant here since all I tried so far is similar to walking around in circles

Comment: Change hosts 2mb is pathetic

Answer (score -2):

```
$aConfig['upload_path'] = 'path';//path where to upload file

$aConfig['allowed_types'] = 'mime type';// the file format which has to accepted

$aConfig['file_name'] = strtolower(date('Y').$_FILES['file']['name']);

$this->upload->initialize($aConfig);
$this->upload->do_upload('pdf');
```

Dont define any file limit like this